# What is the number of characters in a python uuid (type 4)?

Tags: python, uuid

I'm building a database to hold a uuid generated by the python `uuid4` method - however, the documentation doesn't mention how many chars the uuid is!

I'm not overly familiar with uuids, so i don't know if all languages generate the same length for a uuid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a standard for UUIDs, so they're the same in all languages. However, there is a string representation and a binary representation. The normal string representation (`str(myuuid)`) looks like `42c151a8-b22b-4cd5-b103-21bdb882e489` and is 36 characters. The binary representation, `myuuid.bytes` (or `bytes_le`, but stay consistent with it when reconstructing the UUID objects), is 16 bytes. You can also get the string representation with no hyphens (32 characters) with `myuuid.hex`.

You should be aware that some databases have a specific UUID type for storing UUIDs. What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Another common representation is the 36-character version without the dashes.

Comment: mysql and sqlite - anything specific i should know about them?

Comment: @bharal You can use char(36) or binary(16) in either of them; note that the mysql UUID() function returns the uuid in text format, so if you intend to use this text format may be easier, but using binary of course takes less space